# App takes 3 minutes to load with debug mode on device. Runs great any other way

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, ios5, ios6

My app takes over 3 minutes to load when connected to XCode 4.6.3 and running on my device (iPhone 4). I've been working on this app for a long time and it contains around 90 `ViewController`s. To isolate the problem I've created a new `ViewController` in the interface builder and added a UIButton to it. The `ViewController` doesn't have any class attached to it. This `ViewController` is set to be the initial `ViewController`.

**My device connected to XCode** -> Splash -> 3 minutes - > `ViewController` with a `UIBUtton`

**My device NOT connected to XCode** (running the same app from last state from springboard) -> Splash -> 1 second - > `ViewController` with a `UIBUtton`

**Other device connected to XCode** -> Splash -> 1 second - > `ViewController` with a `UIBUtton`

**My device connected to XCode and running instruments** -> Splash -> 1 second - > `ViewController` with a `UIBUtton`

On the simulator it runs fine,

my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is empty besides `return YES;`.

Other apps run fine on debug mode on my device. I have no idea what can cause such a thing.
Things I've tried:

1. Checked my profiles on the device.
2. Did an hard reset to the device.
3. Delete the app from the springboard.
4. Deleted the app derived data.

**My problem isn't build time. If I'll run my original app with XCode on my device it would take 3 minutes to load the first view controller and then another 3 minutes to load the alertview I have there. This is defiantly not normal behaviour.**

Any one experienced something similar to the above? I'm running out of ideas to try.

Comment: Is it not because when running on whilst plugged into xcode it also builds the app so this could take time to do, where as when not connected to xcode it has already built and is just loading the app. I believe if you did clean build then run it would take even longer.

Comment: When you run from Xcode the app is built and installed on the device before running.  Also, you're attached to the console, so if there's extensive logging that takes time.  3 minutes is on the high side, but so is 90 VCs.

Comment: I'm not talking about the build time. I'm talking about the time it takes to move from the splash screen to the first viewcontroller. If i'll run my original app it would take a few minutes for each chunk of code. splash -> 3 minutes -> AlertView -> 3 minutes and so on. This is defiantly not normal behaviour.

Comment: I should also mention that the above doesn't happen on other devices.